# Compare video with ffmpeg add text

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying compare two video files and add text:

```
ffmpeg -i MAH01787.mp4 -i wynik.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] crop=iw/2:ih, pad=2*iw:ih, drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=arial.ttf:text="orginalne video" [left]; [1:v] crop=iw/2:ih, drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=arial.ttf:text="po kompresji" [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -map [out] -map 0:1 -c:v ffv1 -c:a copy polaczone.mp4
pause
```

Dont work.
Error:

> [NULL @ 05bd97c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'video [left]; [1:
>   v] crop=iw/2:ih, drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=arial.ttf:text=po'
>   video [left]; [1:v] crop=iw/2:ih, drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=arial.ttf:text=p
>   o: Invalid argument

What am I doing wrong that it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

> `[NULL @ 05bd97c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'video...`

Problem: The nested double quotes are being interpreted as two separate sets of quotes. Use single quotes (`'`) in your `text` option instead of double quotes (`"`):

Solution: Change `text="orginalne video"` to `text='orginalne video'` and change `text="po kompresji"` to `text='po kompresji'`.

> `Could not find tag for codec ffv1 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

Problem: `-c:v ffv1` cannot be used with MP4 container format.

Solution: Use a different encoder, such as `-c:v libx264`, or use a different output container format, such as `.mkv`.

> `Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

Problem: Stream copying (`-c:v copy`) is not possible with filtered video.

Solution: Do not use `-c:v copy` when filtering. Change it to `-c:v libx264` or some other encoder name.

Comment: sorry what exactly?

Comment: I can not edit the formatting error.
Let me give you as text on the paste

Comment: @JoeSkurczysyn I didn't notice you tried to use ffv1 in MP4 when I provided the full command. Answer updated with a solution for each of the encountered issues.